# MVC PagedList EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing Retain search result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

The `EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing` is working just fine, but every time I click the next page, it will not retain the search or filtered result.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing` is. As far as I'm aware that's not a native part of PagedList. Perhaps you're using a forked version or some additional Nuget package that adds on this functionality?

However, it probably doesn't matter because the problem here is likely the same regardless whether you were working with AJAX or standard page links. You have to include everything from the querystring you want to be persisted in the actual page links. Otherwise, the URL only includes the page number and your other query string params get dropped.

The [docs](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) have a section on creating custom page links:

> To add "foo=bar" to the querystring of each link, you can pass the values into the RouteDictionary parameter of Url.Action:
>
> @Html.PagedListPager( myList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, foo = "bar" }) )
>
> Please note that Url.Action is a method provided by the Asp.Net MVC framework - not the PagedList library.

You simply need to add each of your possible querystring params in there where `foo` is in the same code:

```
@Html.PagedListPager( myList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, search = Request["search"], filter = Request["filer"] }) )
```